# Link to open a download dialog box

Tags: html, image, download, hyperlink

When I create a link to an image I'd like for a download dialog box to open when clicking it instead of the user going to a page containing the image. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible, but it has to be done on the server side. Two great solutions were provided in [answer to this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509056/how-to-create-a-link-that-triggers-file-download). Try out the top two ranked answers.

If you are using a different server technology (other than Apache or PHP), update your question to include those details so we can provide more detailed help.