# How to denied display images, PDF files - and allow only download them?

Tags: html, file, browser

I have an images uploaded on my FTP and because they are really big (sometimes bigger than 10MB), their display takes lot of times, sometimes are not displayed at all.

That's why I would like to denied displaying these files and allow to user only download them - how to do that?

Comment: What is the bandwidth difference between display and download?

Comment: What to you mean "display" ? Use a browser by http to fetch and display them ? And "download" ? Is that only by ftp ? Do you want to authorize ftp and forbid http access to those files ?

Comment: Sorry, that's not possible with HTML.

Comment: for instance, when I have on page PDF file and link to it, so after click on this link will be the content of this PDF file displayed in the browser. But, I would need instead this display download dialog after click on the link to PDF file.

Comment: The medium is different (text vs video), but as long as you're serving the data from a webserver, this still applies: [Is it possible to protect from downloading a video from a site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790190/is-it-possible-to-protect-from-downloading-a-video-from-a-site)

Comment: OTOH, you may be *actually* wishing for something slightly different: if you just want that the images etc. are downloaded **by default**, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648967/force-download-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1509097/984621) is what I have been looking for.

Into the `.htaccess`

```
<Files *.pdf>
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```