# download link in an html web site can't showing dialog box

Tags: html, download

I have an html web site. Here I need to write an `<a >` tag to download a PDF file. See my code

```
<a  href="brochure/brochure.pdf" target="_blank" ><img src="images/downloads.jpg" alt="Downloads" width="258" height="64" border="0" /></a>
```

But when i click on the download button, the pdf file will be opened.

I need to show the dialog box having save and open option as usual

Please reply me...
Thanks

Comment: why dont you zip your pdf file......

Comment: You should use force download apart form direct link of PDF. But you must use any server side language to achive this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force a pdf download automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598658/how-to-force-a-pdf-download-automatically)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a link that triggers file download?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509056/how-to-create-a-link-that-triggers-file-download)

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to force the download at PDF file, Try Content-Type: application/download and let me know if its works or not